# What is the correct way to identify an Exception?

Tags: python

If exceptions are always fatal, making use of them in Python is easy

```
# moduleB.py
import moduleC
```

But evaluating an exception requires more than just it's type, we often need to determine where an exception came from

```
# moduleA.py
try:
   import moduleB
except ImportError as e:
    print e
    if str(e) == "No module named moduleB":
        pass
    else:
        raise
```

In some projects this pattern results in a lot of code that is not easy to read. Is this the best way to ensure that I'm catching a local exception? I would like to be able write

```
import moduleB else pass
```

Comment: Excellent question. Looking longer-term, we should ask the Core Python folks to start adding attributes to system exceptions like this; `ImportError` should have attributes identifying both the module doing the importing, and the name that could not be imported. I would file a bug on the Python issue tracker asking for this, so that eventually, someday, we can give this Stack Overflow question a better answer. :)

Comment: If `moduleC` doesn't exist, or some other ImportError occurs, then `moduleB` **will still not be imported**, regardless of what the error message says. So I can't fathom a situation in which you really care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but the example you posted is the canonical Way Of Doing It. Python doesn't have any syntax for catching the exception raised by the `import` statement but not by something below it.

Just a small warning, though: `str(e)` can cause unicode errors if `e`'s message is unicode. You can fix that by using `repr(e)`.

Comment: Oh, wait, this is Py3k we're talking about. In that case, I don't think `str(e)` will be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

No, don't try to analyse the error string. You can log the exception for debugging if you want, but if it's "import if you can", then this will suffice:

```
try:
    import foo
except ImportError:
    pass # or foo = None or whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, parsing the string is the only viable solution, but note that you don't need to do it: what is the difference if the `moduleB` or if it is a module imported by the `moduleB` not to be found?

If you are throwing custom exceptions, you can provide additional information when you raise them:

```
raise Exception(12)  # 12 is the error code
```

and then get it through the `args` property:

```
if e.args[0] == 12:
    handle()
```

A better way may be to subclass `Exception` and provide your own properties (for example `error_code` or `module_name`).

Comment: A possible difference is: I distribute moduleA, and also optional component moduleB. If moduleB is not present, that's fine. If moduleB **is** present, but importing it causes an error, then that's a bug I want to be notified about.

Comment: Then you can always wrap moduleA import statement with a try-except clause and raise `ModuleBHasFailingImportsNotification`

Comment: You mean wrap every import *inside* moduleB with a try-except clause that re-raises a non ImportError exception? That works, but you have to be sure that protocol is always followed. Furthermore it's not something you can do if moduleB is actually a third-party library. I think the point is that simply catching ImportError when importing a module that may not be there has the potential to silently ignore bugs, unless you can query the ImportError for the cause.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    import moduleB
except ImportError:
    pass
```

This ought to be both sufficient and succinct enough.